# Global varible showing runtime errors in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using mean.js(express + angular). I have defined a global varible. It is working properly. But when i run using grunt command i am getting errors.

```
     global.clients = [];
     cients[socket.id] = socket;

     // in some other file

     var socketid1 = clients[id];
```

This is working properly for me. But in my terminal

```
  clients[socket.id] = socket;
             ^ 'clients' is not defined.
  var socketid1 = clients[id];
                  ^ 'clients' is not defined.
```

I am getting these warnings . How to clear this warnings? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you using 'global'? There doesn't appear to be a need for that. Try this tutorial to learn about scope in js http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/

Comment: I want  to use that varible in other files too

Comment: well access it with global.varname

Comment: while accessing variable with global.varname , it will create a new such variable.  But the methods that i used is working fine for me. but i want to remove those warning in my console